# How to deal with unzip error on a large file in OSX?

Tags: error, macos, zip

I downloaded the latest Raspbian image from the raspberrypi.org website on my Mac running OS X 10.10.5
The SHA-1 checksum agrees with that listed on the website.

When I try to extract using `unzip` I get the following error

```
warning [2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.zip]:  76 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.zip]:  reported length of central directory is
  -76 bytes too long (Atari STZip zipfile?  J.H.Holm ZIPSPLIT 1.1
  zipfile?).  Compensating...
   skipping: 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.img  need PK compat. v4.5 (can do v2.1)

note:  didn't find end-of-central-dir signature at end of central dir.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I managed to unzip it with tar.

```
tar xzvf 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.zip
```

Requires no installation of additional software

Comment: Magic! The 'z' is not needed  `tar -xvf 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.zip`

Answer (score 7):

The ZIP file can also be uncompressed using `ditto`, no software installation needed:

```
ditto -x -k 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.zip .
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 7za from p7zip installed from brew:

```
brew install p7zip
```

and then unzip using the command

```
 7za x big_file.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently a known "bug" in OS X Archiver, which is unable to handle zip greater than 4 GB.

Comment: yeah archiver seems to create .cpgz file out of it (i.e. "corrupted zip rezipped" file or some odd).  And the "unzip" command line also doesn't work on it, but the other answers here seemed to work fine. Weird. (apparently some larger files are "zip64" format?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439742/modern-ie-windows-10-virtualbox-for-mac-zip-file-corrupt

Answer (score 0):

I tried the command line solutions listed here to a 18GB zip to no avail. I was able to extract the problematic zips using:

**The Unarchiver**

Free software available through the app store.